# Oracle Recursion

Tags: c#, oracle

I want list all SOURCE_ID if the source has destination, the query below not work probably !!

```
select SOURCE_ID,
        LINK_TYPE,
        DESTINATION_ID 
from LINK_TABLE
where link_table.link_type=1 
and link_table.destination_is_deleted=0
START WITH link_table.source_id='100'
CONNECT BY PRIOR link_table.source_id=link_table.destination_id
```

Sample data

```
SOURCE_ID |  DESTINATION_ID | LINK_TYPE| DESTINATION_IS_DELETED|
----------|-----------------|----------|-----------------------|
100       |      1500       |    1     |             0         |
100       |       1200      |    1     |             0         |
100       |      1300       |    1     |             1         |
1500      |       600       |    1     |             0         |
1500      |       700       |    1     |             0         |
700       |        88       |    1     |             0         |
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, and thank you for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to walk the hierarchy from the root nodes to the leaves this is what you need:

```
select SOURCE_ID,
        LINK_TYPE,
        DESTINATION_ID 
from LINK_TABLE
where link_table.link_type=1 
and link_table.destination_is_deleted=0
START WITH link_table.source_id='100'
CONNECT BY PRIOR link_table.destination_id = link_table.source_id
/
```

It's just a matter of swapping the referenced columns in the CONNECT BY PRIOR clause. Unfortunately the Oracle syntax is not intuitive here: I've been using it for over twenty years and I still have to test a query to make sure I've got them the right way round :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query structure to solve the issue.

```
select SOURCE_ID,DESTINATION_ID,link_table.source_class,link_table.linktype,link_table.destination_class
from LINK_TABLE
where (link_table.source_id in( select link_table.DESTINATION_ID from link_table where link_table.source_id='100'and link_table.linktype=1 and link_table.destination_isdeleted=0 ))
and (link_table.linktype=1) or (link_table.source_id='100')
```